# Uninitialized constant Instagram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, instagram

I have a site, that is using Instagram api and there I'm getting this kind of error, when I'm running "rails c" or "rails server", **/vagrant/Documents/RubyProjects/photo/config/initializers/instagram.rb:3:in `': uninitialized constant Instagram (NameError)**
I suppose it means that rails can't find instagram class or module. But there's a definition of instagram gem in my gemfile ***gem 'instagram'*** and in the bundle show command contains *** instagram (1.1.1)***. The error is pointing at this:

```
require "instagram"

Instagram.configure do |config|   <- where error points to
  config.client_id = "*****************"
  config.client_secret = "*************************"
  config.access_token = "***************************************"
end
```

I'm a beginner in all this rails things, so I really don't, what's wrong here. Thx for answering in advance.

Comment: Your config folder should be at the project root. Something like this:
RubyProjects/config/initializers/instagram.rb

Comment: check that gem `instagram` does not belong to any group (for example production). Try to run `bundle exec rails c`

Comment: I had a similar problem with `Omniauth` gem. I really don't remember how I solved that issue, but you can do it from scratch. Comment all the code in `instagram.rb`, remove gem line from Gemfile, delete the gem (also delete the instagram gem folder manually if it exists) and run your application. If it works, then add the gem line in Gemfile, install it, then run your application again. If it works, then uncomment everything in `instagram.rb` file and try running again.

Comment: About 1 comment my project is named photo, so it's in the root folder, about 2 comment I don't understand "check that gem instagram does not belong to any group" can you pls explain, what group, where and how :) and about 3 comment, I did all that stuff and the problem comes up with the code in `instagram.rb`, the projects works if I comment all lines of code in `instagram.rb`

Comment: Try changing the name of your initializer file to something other than `instagram.rb` or see if it works without the initial `require` statement. I think the issue is that you are requiring `instagram(.rb)` from the gem but that is also the name of your initializer file.

Comment: Here's an [example repo](https://github.com/O-I/instagram_example) of how to set up Rails to work with the instagram gem if you're interested.

Comment: tried first and second part didn't work again the same problem `/vagrant/Documents/RubyProjects/photo/config/initializers/instagram_conf.rb:1:in ``<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Instagram`

Comment: Tried running as Harsh Gupta told and I have a new error in instagram gem `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/instagram-1.1.1/lib/instagram/configuration.rb:30:in ``<module:Configuration>': uninitialized constant Instagram::Configuration::Faraday (NameError)`
This comes when I just installed gem and did `bundle install` all code in `instagram_conf.rb` is commented.