# Uninitialized constant Instagram v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, instagram

This question is a copy of [Uninitialized constant Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344286/uninitialized-constant-instagram), but with minor different details (and because no one really answered last one). And again I have a site that is using Instagram API. And when I'm trying run `rails server` (when I just added `instagram` gem), I get this kind of error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Instagram::Configuration::Faraday
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/instagram-1.0.0/lib/instagram/configuration.rb:29:in `<module:Configuration>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/instagram-1.0.0/lib/instagram/configuration.rb:6:in `<module:Instagram>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/instagram-1.0.0/lib/instagram/configuration.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/instagram-1.0.0/lib/instagram.rb:2:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/instagram-1.0.0/lib/instagram.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
/vagrant/Documents/RubyProjects/instagram_example/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/vagrant/Documents/RubyProjects/instagram_example/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is quite different from last question, because I'm getting error in gem. I tried to clone [this example](https://github.com/O-I/instagram_example) with Instagram API, but I get the same error. My friend tried to run this example and it works for him. Here's my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'instagram'
gem 'dotenv-rails'

gem 'pry-rails', group: :development
```

This made me think so far to that point, that my Ubuntu 14.04 works badly.

**Solution**:
Use ruby installed on host, not on vagrant or another virtual machines or virtual boxes.

Comment: Did you remember to `bundle install` after editing your Gemfile?

Comment: Of course, I did that.

Comment: On the prev post you wrote `show command contains * instagram (1.1.1)* ` but your stack trace is running the `instagram-1.0.0` gem.
Run `gem list|grep instagram`. Are there mutliple versions installed?

Comment: yep, because as I said here, I cloned this project from repo in the link upper and tried to test it.

Comment: but if `bundle show` says 1.1.1 and the stacktrace says 1.0.0 you project is running the wrong version at the moment. It is running outside of bundler context. You should be running all gem commands like rails either with `bundle exec` prefixed or through generated binstubs

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
gem "instagram", "~> 1.1.1"
```

to the Gemfile, then:

```
  $ bundle install
  $ bundle exec rails c
```

then on rails console type

```
 Instagram
```

It should always return the class object

Edit 1:

And do not forget to stop spring then requiring new gems into a rails proejct

```
$ bin/spring stop
```

Comment: rails console doesn't open and the error is still the same 
`vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/Documents/RubyProjects/instagram_example$ bundle exec rails c
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/instagram-1.1.1/lib/instagram/configuration.rb:30:in ``<module:Configuration>': uninitialized constant Instagram::Configuration::Faraday (NameError)`

Comment: wtf? cloned the example project. did the steps. Works like a charm

Comment: `vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/Documents/RubyProjects/instagram_example$ bundle show`
`* instagram (1.1.1)`

Comment: the only difference is, i'm using a Mac. Maybe something with your vagrant vm setup. What is you host OS? Try it without vagrant

Comment: As I said it worked , when my friend did it on his laptop and on mine it didn't work, that's why I'm trying to seek answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 lts, it's in the description of question as well. Well without vagrant it'll take some time to put ruby on OS and tralala etc.

Comment: So why are u using vagrant? Try with native install. I also use ruby 2.1.2. U can safely upgrade your ruby. 2.1.1 has some severe memory leaks by the way

Comment: Well its convient at least, but well gonna try that with native as you say and will reply when I'm done.

Comment: The error is also strange. There is no Instagram::Configuration::Faraday class in the Instagram gem. Faraday is just used within Istagram::Configuration module. I suppose this is happening because the Farraday dependency was not loaded properly. U can also try adding `gem faraday` explicitly before instagram

Comment: I also see you are requiring the spring prelaoder. Have you generated the spring binstubs in bin folder. They will be used automatically. On every new gem install you have to run `spring stop` before starting rails otherwise changes will not be detected. Try just uncommenting spring in the gemfile and check if this error happens again

Comment: Checked the bin folder of the example project. It's using spring binstubs. See bin/rails.rb, it's requiring spring. I guess that was it. Just run `bin/spring stop` , then `bin/rails c`

Comment: I was about to kill the world with my telekinetic powers, but I made up instagram working. As dre-hh said, I just replaced ruby,rvm,rails ... on my host machine, not on vagrant. I don't know why it worked, but it worked.